# Do I need to prove rational number is discontinued on the number axis (irrational numbers are filled in between) and solve this question?

Tags: calculus, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

We define the Riemann function $R:\Bbb R\to\Bbb Q$ by $$R(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{q} &\text{if }x=\frac pq\text{ for }\ p\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\},\ q\in\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}\text{ and }\operatorname{gcd}(p,q)=1\\
 0&\text{if }x\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q\\
 1&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$$

Prove that for any $a \in\Bbb R$ ，$\lim_{x\to a}R(x)=0$

I tried to solve is using the fact that the irrationals are dense in real number, but I had no idea how to write it. While searching on internet, I wonder would this idea contradicts Dirichlet function?

Comment: What do you mean by $a \in R$ if $R$ is a function?

Comment: What does $2^*$ mean?

Comment: I also presume $q>0$.

Comment: Hint : The irrational numbers are dense in the real numbers

Comment: @gerw a in real number, while R is the name of the funciton. Sorry for the misleading.

Comment: @Théophile oh that is just the question number.

Comment: @Peter I tried to solve is using your idea, but I had no idea how to write it. While searching on internet, I wonder would this idea contradicts Dirichlet function?

Comment: @YongKinChong I noticed that this is not enough to solve the question. What you also need that in every neighborhood of $a$ , for every $\epsilon>0$, there are only finite many real numbers $x$ with $|R(x)|\ge \epsilon$

Comment: It's not enough to solve and it doesn't need to be proven or assumed at all.

Comment: @YongKinChong Hey, wanted to let you know that the site policy is that people should include context in their question like what have you tried to solve the problem, or where you found the problem etc. I've edited this question with info you provided from the comments which should probably be enough. Anyway welcome to Math.SE :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  You do not need to prove or assume any such thing. Although it is absolutely true.

You need to prove that for any $a \in \mathbb R$ and any $\epsilon > 0$ that there is a $\delta$ so that 1) either $0 \not \in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$ or $a = 0$. and 2) that if there are any rational numbers (other than $0$) in $(a-\delta, a+\delta)$[$*$] they are such that their denominators are all larger than $\frac 1{\epsilon}$

That will be enough to prove it even without proving that irrationals and the rationals are mutually dense.

Hint: If $a \ne 0$ find $q$ so that $\frac jq < |a| < \frac {j+1}q$.  Any rational $r$ so that $\frac jq < r <\frac {j+1}q$ will have denominators that are larger than $q$ and $R(r) < \frac 1q$.  ..... So if $q > \frac 1{\epsilon}$......

=====

[$*$] Of course, there always *will* be rational numbers in $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$.  But you don't have to prove there will be.  You just have to assume there *might* be.  As for the irrationals since $|R(x) - 0| = 0 < \epsilon$ they are trivial to deal with.  You don't have to prove there will be but just demonstrate that *if* there are $|R(x) - 0| = 0 < \epsilon$.

Comment: I don't get the second point 2) . Does the $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ gives a large integer? why rational numbers should be larger than $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ ?

Comment: If all the rationals $s_i$ have denominators  $q_i > \frac 1 {\epsilon}$ then $R(s_i) = \frac 1{q_i} < \epsilon$.

Comment: The rational number are *not* larger than $\frac 1 {\epsilon}$.  You want to find an interval around $a$ where *all* the rationals have *denominators* that are larger than $\frac 1{\epsilon}$.  If the *denominators* of all $s_i$ in an interval are larger than $\frac 1{\epsilon}$ what is $R(s_i)$.

Comment: That hard part is proving that such an interval will exist for all real *a* and all positive epsilon.